# Build a public library with Ubercart

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I want to build a library that includes a collection of music and video books I could rent to a customer on a day basis charge. I want to add fines for the customers if there is a due. How can I do it using Ubercart?

Comment: I think Ubercart is for buying products. I don't think it is fully suited for specially rentals. You can also check in joomla/Drupal paid extensions which provide such functionality

Comment: Instead of Ubercart, I'd look into commerce for Drupal 7 (successor to Ubercart). It seems to be more flexible and powerful